# Jasmine 2.0 how to wait real time before running an expectation

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I am trying to test the postMessage API as there is a slight delay before message are receive i can not run expectation right after sending a message.

In jasmine 1.3 i used to wait() a few milliseconds before running expectation and that worked fine. However with jasmine 2.0 wait() is deprecated and it now seems that everything inside a setTimeout do not get run unless done() is called, witch in my case doesn't cut it as i actually want to wait real time before running my expectation..

Not sure if that all make sense, if it does I'd love some pointers on how I could go about this.
Thanks!

Comment: I have lots of questions but to start. Why you wan to test and Ajax call?

Comment: Are you using karma or SpecRunner.html?

Comment: What are using to make your Ajax calls?

Comment: @Dalorzo I am using testem for running tests, I am not testing an ajax call but the postMessage API. From the moment you send a message using post message and the moment the message is receive there is a small delay, like 1,2 ms

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rather than waiting some number of milliseconds, jasmine has hooks to wait until a function returns. [This page](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/test-asynchronous-methods-using-the-jasmine-runs-and-waitfor-methods.html#fbid=MlgUNsFDSQb) has some good example, and I've copied one here to show a specific way of testing ajax callbacks. Just add a spy as a callback to your function and wait for that callback to be executed.

```
it("should make a real AJAX request", function () {
    var callback = jasmine.createSpy();
    makeAjaxCall(callback);
    waitsFor(function() {
        return callback.callCount > 0;
    }, "The Ajax call timed out.", 5000);

    runs(function() {
        expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

EDIT:

Since you're testing that your application makes a specific callback, you can just replace that callback with a spy instead of creating a new one like I did.

Jasmine 2.0 added a "done" style callback, so you should be able to do something like: (I haven't tested the syntax of this but hopefully a good start)

```
it("should make an ajax callback with jasmine 2.0", function(done)) {
    // this is the object you are testing - assume it has the ajax method you want to call and the method that gets called when the ajax method is finished
    var myObject
    spyOn(myObject, "callback").andCallFake(function() {
        done();        
    });    
    myObject.makeAjaxCall();    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for input Jeff, but in my case it doesn't cut it. My public API just listen for message from postMessage and answer them using an other message, so i can only test that when a certain type of message is received then my application sends back the appropriate response. Problem is that postMessage API take like 1,2 ms to reach,  so i do need to wait. Beside the page you linked to is for jasmine 1.3 and is method used is deprecated

Comment: @silkAdmin I edited the post with some additional info - does this help?

Comment: @silkAdmin based on the information provided I think JeffStorey approach looks fine. I am using jasmine 2.0. and I have waitsFor available

Answer (score 15):

This works for me:

```
beforeAll(function (done) {
    setTimeout(done, 5000);
});
```

The beforeAll function occurred first, but it will end when you invoke the done callback function. So if you use setTimeout function with 5000, it will wait 5000 milliseconds before continuing.

Comment: I wanted to see stuff was properly drawn. For me I found using `afterAll` instead of `beforeAll` kept the drawn thing in the browser window for the timeout time.