# How to test code inside $(window).on("load", function() {}); in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a javascript below, which appends a DIV on page load and hides it after 3 sec.

```
var testObj = {
   initialize: function() {
    var that = this;
    $(window).on("load", function() {  
        (function ($) { //Append Div
            $('body').append("<div>TEST</div>");
        })(jQuery);
        that.hideAppendedDiv();
    });
   },
   hideAppendedDiv: function() {  //Hide appended Div after 3s
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("div").hide();
    }, 3000);
   }
};

//call Initialize method
testObj.initialize();
```

How to write Jasmine test cases for the methods in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you don't really want to test a Javascript function such as `$(window).on('load')...` , but that your own function `hideAppendedDiv()` get's called from $(window).on('load'). Furthermore, you want to make sure that the function `hideAppendedDiv()` works as well.

IMO, you need two expects.

Somewhere in your setup beforeEach function:

```
beforeEach(function () {
    spyOn(testObj , 'hideAppendedDiv').and.callThrough();
});
```

**Expectations**

```
it('expects hideAppendedDiv() to have been called', function () {

    // make the call to the initialize function
    testObj.initialize ();

    // Check internal function
    expect(testObj.hideAppendedDiv).toHaveBeenCalled();
});

it('expects hideAppendedDiv() to hide div', function () {

    // make the call to the hideAppendedDiv function
    testObj.hideAppendedDiv();

    // Check behavior
    expect(... check the div ...) 
});
```

**Edit**

---

Just to be clear, [Jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/2.4/introduction.html) executes all the expects in order. Now, if you have two functions `fn_1()`, and `fn_2()` and you want to test that they were called in order you can setup yet another spi function that returns a specific value, or a sequential and incremental set of values every time it is called.

```
beforeEach(function () {
    spyOn(testObj , 'fn_1').and.returnValues(1, 2, 3);
    spyOn(testObj , 'fn_2').and.returnValues(4, 5, 6);
});
```

The first time fn_1 is called it will return 1, respectively fn_2 will return 4.

That is just one of the ways, but you have to get creative when testing.

Now if you want to test that a function was called after x amount of time [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21176916/4775223) is a post that already explains it.

Comment: 'expects hideAppendedDiv() to have been called' test case is failing, the code, test is passing only after moving the code $('body').append("<div>TEST</div>");   out of  $(window).on("load", function() {  });

Comment: Create a new method in your object "testObj" which contains the code from the window.load callback, in your init method pass this to the window.load as a callback method.

Now when you test this code, you aren't interested in testing the window.load event, you can simply invoke the two methods which are actually delivering value.

Comment: How to test the execution order of functions , example testFn2() should be called after testFn2(), If i use toHaveBeenCalled() in any order it gives true. but how to test the execution flow.

Comment: and also how to test the setTimout, like how to test the hideDiv method has been fired exactly after 3000ms.

Comment: I added an edit to my answer as it was too long for a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to test the window load event, if you move the append code out of the anonymous function call and pass it into the event handler instead you can test the functionality in exactly the same way you would anything else and your code will be better structured.