# Prevent Jasmine Test expect() Resolving Before JS Finished Executing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, phantomjs, karma-jasmine

I am hoping you can help. I am fairly new to Unit Testing. I have a Karma + Jasmine set up which is running a PhantomJS browser. This is all good.

What I am struggling with is I have a link on the page, when this link is clicked it injects some HTML. I want to test that the HTML has been injected.

Now at this point, I have the test working but only sometimes, from what I can figure out if my JS runs fast enough the HTML gets injected before the `expect()` is run. If not the test fails.

How can I make my Jasmine test wait for all JS to finish executing before the `expect()` is run?

The test in question is `it("link can be clicked to open a modal", function() {`

**modal.spec.js**

```
const modalTemplate = require('./modal.hbs');

import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime';
import 'core-js/features/array/from';
import 'core-js/features/array/for-each';
import 'core-js/features/object/assign';
import 'core-js/features/promise';

import Modal from './modal';

describe("A modal", function() {

    beforeAll(function() {
        const data = {"modal": {"modalLink": {"class": "", "modalId": "modal_1", "text": "Open modal"}, "modalSettings": {"id": "", "modifierClass": "", "titleId": "", "titleText": "Modal Title", "closeButton": true, "mobileDraggable": true}}};
        const modal = modalTemplate(data);
        document.body.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', modal );
    });

    it("link exists on the page", function() {
        const modalLink = document.body.querySelector('[data-module="modal"]');
        expect(modalLink).not.toBeNull();
    });

    it("is initialised", function() {
        spyOn(Modal, 'init').and.callThrough();
        Modal.init();

        expect(Modal.init).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    it("link can be clicked to open a modal", function() {
        const modalLink = document.body.querySelector('[data-module="modal"]');
        modalLink.click();

        const modal = document.body.querySelector('.modal');
        expect(modal).not.toBeNull();
    });

    afterAll(function() {

        console.log(document.body);

        // TODO: Remove HTML

    });

});
```

**EDIT - More Info**

To further elaborate on this, The link [Jasmine 2.0 how to wait real time before running an expectation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21176795/jasmine-2-0-how-to-wait-real-time-before-running-an-expectation) put in the comments has helped me understand a bit better, I think. So what we are saying it we want to `spyOn` the function and wait for it to be called and then initiate a callback which then resolves the test.

Great.

My next issue is, if you look at the structure of my `ModalViewModel` class below, I need to be able to `spyOn` `insertModal()` to be able to do this, but the only function that is accessible in `init()`. What would I do to be able to move forward with this method?

```
import feature from 'feature-js';
import { addClass, removeClass, hasClass } from '../../01-principles/utils/classModifiers';
import makeDraggableItem from '../../01-principles/utils/makeDraggableItem';
import '../../01-principles/utils/polyfil.nodeList.forEach'; // lt IE 12

const defaultOptions = {
    id: '',
    modifierClass: '',
    titleId: '',
    titleText: 'Modal Title',
    closeButton: true,
    mobileDraggable: true,
};

export default class ModalViewModel {
    constructor(module, settings = defaultOptions) {
        this.options = Object.assign({}, defaultOptions, settings);
        this.hookModalLink(module);

    }

    hookModalLink(module) {
        module.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();


            this.populateModalOptions(e);
            this.createModal(this.options);
            this.insertModal();

            if (this.options.closeButton) {
                this.hookCloseButton();
            }

            if (this.options.mobileDraggable && feature.touch) {
                this.hookDraggableArea();
            }

            addClass(document.body, 'modal--active');

        }, this);
    }

    populateModalOptions(e) {
        this.options.id = e.target.getAttribute('data-modal');
        this.options.titleId = `${this.options.id}_title`;
    }

    createModal(options) {
        // Note: As of ARIA 1.1 it is no longer correct to use aria-hidden when aria-modal is used
        this.modalTemplate = `<section id="${options.id}" class="modal ${options.modifierClass}" role="dialog" aria-modal="true" aria-labelledby="${options.titleId}" draggable="true">
                                ${options.closeButton ? '<a href="#" class="modal__close icon--cross" aria-label="Close" ></a>' : ''}
                                ${options.mobileDraggable ? '<a href="#" class="modal__mobile-draggable" ></a>' : ''}
                                <div class="modal__content">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="columns small-12">
                                            <h2 class="modal__title" id="${options.titleId}">${options.titleText}</h2>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </section>`;

        this.modal = document.createElement('div');
        addClass(this.modal, 'modal__container');
        this.modal.innerHTML = this.modalTemplate;
    }

    insertModal() {
        document.body.appendChild(this.modal);
    }

    hookCloseButton() {
        this.closeButton = this.modal.querySelector('.modal__close');

        this.closeButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            this.removeModal();
            removeClass(document.body, 'modal--active');
        });
    }

    hookDraggableArea() {
        this.draggableSettings = {
            canMoveLeft: false,
            canMoveRight: false,
            moveableElement: this.modal.firstChild,
        };

        makeDraggableItem(this.modal, this.draggableSettings, (touchDetail) => {
            this.handleTouch(touchDetail);
        }, this);
    }

    handleTouch(touchDetail) {
        this.touchDetail = touchDetail;
        const offset = this.touchDetail.moveableElement.offsetTop;

        if (this.touchDetail.type === 'tap') {
            if (hasClass(this.touchDetail.eventObject.target, 'modal__mobile-draggable')) {

                if (offset === this.touchDetail.originY) {
                    this.touchDetail.moveableElement.style.top = '0px';
                } else {
                    this.touchDetail.moveableElement.style.top = `${this.touchDetail.originY}px`;
                }

            } else if (offset > this.touchDetail.originY) {
                this.touchDetail.moveableElement.style.top = `${this.touchDetail.originY}px`;
            } else {
                this.touchDetail.eventObject.target.click();
            }
        } else if (this.touchDetail.type === 'flick' || (this.touchDetail.type === 'drag' && this.touchDetail.distY > 200)) {

            if (this.touchDetail.direction === 'up') {

                if (offset < this.touchDetail.originY) {
                    this.touchDetail.moveableElement.style.top = '0px';
                } else if (offset > this.touchDetail.originY) {
                    this.touchDetail.moveableElement.style.top = `${this.touchDetail.originY}px`;
                }

            } else if (this.touchDetail.direction === 'down') {

                if (offset < this.touchDetail.originY) {
                    this.touchDetail.moveableElement.style.top = `${this.touchDetail.originY}px`;
                } else if (offset > this.touchDetail.originY) {
                    this.touchDetail.moveableElement.style.top = '95%';
                }

            }
        } else {
            this.touchDetail.moveableElement.style.top = `${this.touchDetail.moveableElementStartY}px`;
        }
    }

    removeModal() {
        document.body.removeChild(this.modal);
    }

    static init() {
        const instances = document.querySelectorAll('[data-module="modal"]');

        instances.forEach((module) => {
            const settings = JSON.parse(module.getAttribute('data-modal-settings')) || {};
            new ModalViewModel(module, settings);
        });
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

After working through it has been discovered that `.click()` events are asynchronous which is why I am gettnig the race issue. Documentation & Stack Overflow issues thoughtout the web recommend using `createEvent()` and `dispatchEvent()` as PhantomJs does not understand `new MouseEvent()`.

Here is my code which is now trying to do this.

**modal.spec.js**

```
// All my imports and other stuff
// ...

function click(element){
    var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvent');
    event.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    element.dispatchEvent(event);
}

describe("A modal", function() {

    // Some other tests
    // Some other tests

    it("link can be clicked to open a modal", function() {
        const modalLink = document.body.querySelector('[data-module="modal"]');
        click(modalLink);

        const modal = document.body.querySelector('.modal');
        expect(modal).not.toBeNull();
    });

    // After all code
    // ...

});
```

Unfortunately this is producting the same results. 1 step closer but not quite there.

Comment: Please see this link for more help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21176795/jasmine-2-0-how-to-wait-real-time-before-running-an-expectation

Comment: Hey @demouser123, I am not sure if this helps as I am not making an AJAX call, I am only creating a HTML string and injecting it into the DOM.

Comment: @CodyKnapp I actually agree with you, It doesn't really make sense to me either, all I have to go off is in my `afterAll` function the `console.log(document.body);` sometimes has the injected HTML and sometimes it doesn't. My assumption was that it is a race issue but perhaps not?

Comment: After a bit of research (sorry for deleting my comment - I didn't see yours) I found that click is asynchronous.  That is why you're getting this race condition between your assertion and the click event handler you've added.  That was the only thing I saw as possible.  I'm looking around a bit more to see if there's something handy for waiting on the click's entire process to finish.

Comment: @CodyKnapp Ah good to know, thank you for your help, lets hope you can find something as I am stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found a solution.

There are 2 parts to this, the first part came from @CodyKnapp. His insight into a `click()` function running asynchronously helped to solve the first part of the issue.

Here is the code for this part.

**modal.spec.js**

```
// All my imports and other stuff
// ...

function click(element){
    var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvent');
    event.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    element.dispatchEvent(event);
}

describe("A modal", function() {

    // Some other tests
    // Some other tests

    it("link can be clicked to open a modal", function() {
        const modalLink = document.body.querySelector('[data-module="modal"]');
        click(modalLink);

        const modal = document.body.querySelector('.modal');
        expect(modal).not.toBeNull();
    });

    // After all code
    // ...


});
```

This allowed for the code to run synchronously.

The second part was a poor understanding on my part of how to write Jasmine tests. In my original tests I was running `Modal.init()` inside of `it("is initialised", function() {` when actually I want to be running this inside of `beforeAll()`. This fixed the issue I had where my tests would not always be successful.

Here is my final code:

**modal.spec.js**

```
const modalTemplate = require('./modal.hbs');

import '@babel/polyfill';

import Modal from './modal';

function click(element){
    var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvent');
    event.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    element.dispatchEvent(event);
}

describe("A modal", function() {

    beforeAll(function() {
        const data = {"modal": {"modalLink": {"class": "", "modalId": "modal_1", "text": "Open modal"}, "modalSettings": {"id": "", "modifierClass": "", "titleId": "", "titleText": "Modal Title", "closeButton": true, "mobileDraggable": true}}};
        const modal = modalTemplate(data);
        document.body.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', modal );

        spyOn(Modal, 'init').and.callThrough();
        Modal.init();
    });

    it("link exists on the page", function() {
        const modalLink = document.body.querySelector('[data-module="modal"]');
        expect(modalLink).not.toBeNull();
    });

    it("is initialised", function() {
        expect(Modal.init).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    it("link can be clicked to open a modal", function() {
        const modalLink = document.body.querySelector('[data-module="modal"]');
        click(modalLink);

        const modal = document.body.querySelector('.modal');
        expect(modal).not.toBeNull();
    });

    afterAll(function() {

        console.log(document.body);

        // TODO: Remove HTML

    });

});
```

Comment: I'm glad to see you got it all squared away.  I would argue, however, that spying on and testing init is probably not necessary.  If there is not some other verifiable behavior that init is providing, then it might need re-evaluated to see if it's even worth having.

Comment: Hey @CodyKnapp, that's a very good point I will have a think about what is best to test and my general testing strategy. As I said before this is my first go at this so any tips / hints are very welcome! Thanks.

Comment: I would say it really depends on your public interface.  I'm guessing you are working with DOM elements and behaviors from your test... In that case, I would suggest what you test are that the interactions with the DOM behave as you intend.  Whatever has to happen to make that happen is not really relevant to the test as long as the behavior is correct.

Comment: I'm happy to share more thoughts on it - especially if you have specific questions - feel free to message me with any thoughts/questions you have !

Comment: @CodyKnapp Thank you for your help and recommendations, I have refactored my code to work in a more logical way and to test the necessary items. I won't post here as it is not relevant but you have been a great help.

Answer (score 1):

After a touch of research, it looks as though your use of the click event is triggering an asynchronous event loop essentially saying "Hey set this thing to be clicked and then fire all the handlers"

Your current code can't see that and has no real way of waiting for it.  I do believe you should be able to build and dispatch a mouse click event using the info here. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent

I think that should allow you to build a click event and dispatch it onto your element.  The difference is that dispatchEvent is synchronous - it should block your test until the click handlers have completed.  That should allow you to do your assertion without failures or race conditions.

Comment: Awesome this is a step in the right direction thanks. My next hurdle is PhantomJS doesn't support `new MouseEvent()` which is required to use `.dispatchEvent()`.

Comment: I would say that this is the approach if you're not interested in using something like jquery etc.  If you used that you could use jquery's `trigger` function and hand it a callback to do your assertions

Comment: Agreed that jQuery's `trigger` even would probably make this easier but if possible I would really like to avoid bringing jQuery into the mix.